# Embedded Excel file crashes

Tags: vba, excel, ole

I need to put a link to another Excel files in my current Workbook.
This is the part of my VBA code that does that:

```
v_fileNameToImport = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & v_techs(i) & "\" & v_regions(j) & "\Results\" & v_files(k)
v_sheetName = "RESUMO " & v_regions(j)

'Check if there is already a tab for this region
If (SheetExists(v_sheetName)) Then
   Worksheets(v_sheetName).OLEObjects.Add Filename:=v_fileNameToImport, Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, Top:=40, Left:=160, Width:=100, Height:=100
Else
   Set v_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
   v_sheet.Name = v_sheetName
   v_sheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=v_fileNameToImport, Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, Top:=40, Left:=40, Width:=100, Height:=100
End If
```

After running the macro, each file link appears as a blank rectangle instead of an Excel icon. When I click it, it starts to open the other file but crashes right away.

**Edit:** It seems that when I run the macro for the second time, i.e. after already importing the files, it will crash, despites all tabs are deleted when the macro starts. Maybe the reference to the files remains despites its tabs are deleted, what causes a conflict with a new reference to the same file. When running from a fresh file this problem does not happens.

Comment: I would check the contents of `v_fileNameToImport` - object appearing as a blank rectangle suggests that there is no standard icon registered for the file type (i.e. that the files aren't being recognised as Excel files for some reason - maybe your earlier code is giving you the wrong filenames).

Comment: @aucuparia: I've checked that is really a valid path to a excel file. It seems that the icon (IconFileName) has to be explicitly set.

Comment: Regarding the crash when I run the macro twice, I could not figure it out. Even if I loop through the tabs and delete each OLEObject before deleting the tabs it still would crash when the OLEObjects are once again added. Anyway, this will not be a problem since I will not allow the user to run the macro twice.